# Alteon 4408, console connection

Tags: switch

[image]

Hello all,
I have a Alteon 4408 switch.
**Even though I configured the switch as baud rate(9600), stop bit(1), it does not working properly.
It happened like upper picture.**

I changed the baud rate except for 9600. but failed.
and I also changed my console cable. but failed.

In the past, I had dealt with 4408,
At this time, it worked well.. as I used same console cable.

If you know this issue, please contact me.
Regards,

Comment: 9600,8n1 is the default. Either your serial interface is bad or the 4408 isn't running at the default speed. Try other speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may some thing relate to converter which connect your console cable to the USB port in your computer . may you try to used desktop computer with normal serial port and use putty terminal with the next settings

[image]

and it should work .
otherwise you may check the flow control options in the serial part as next

[image]

and try the 4 options . one of them should work

Comment: Thank you sir,But I already tried that.
But failed...
I think it is broken down .. ㅠ_ㅠ ah...
is there anything else that I should try ?